# Javascript height returning "getElementById('div') is null?

Tags: javascript, css, height

k this is probably something very easy but for some reason i am getting an error when trying to use javascript to change style.height.

My javascript looks like this:

```
document.getElementById('div').style.height=100px;
```

I have also tried

```
document.getElementById('div').style.height='100px'; 
document.getElementById('div').style.height='100';
document.getElementById('div').style.height=100;
```

and get the same error every time.

The error i am getting is:

```
document.getElementById('div') is null
```

I get this error in my firebug console.  Thanks.

Comment: Is your <div> tag id set to div? Like so: `<div id="div">`, that is what you are trying to achieve with this code.

Comment: Please show your HTML too. You have an element with an ID of "div"? Or are you trying to grab a div?

Comment: Is the `id` of your `div` element `"div"`?

Comment: I have a div with an id of id='div'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably don't have an element with `id="div"`.

Or you're running your code before the body exists.

Comment: That works.  When i put the code in the header it doesn't work probably because it runs the code before the div.  When i put the javascript at the bottom of the document it works fine.  Thanks you so much.

Answer (score 0):

this have to work fine :

> document.getElementById('div').style.height='100px';

please check your html code, and try in the console :

```
document.getElementById('div').style.height;
```

and see what returns after and before

(maybe its working and you cant see it, you can check it adding an background-color)